# Bootstrap 3.2 navigation bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can somebody please help me with these two questions?

1. What should I do for my navigation to be at the bottom + be sticky and stay at the top once I scroll down past it?
2. My website is a one page site. What should I do for my navigation to switch between different parts of the page?

All of these questions should be used with Bootstrap 3.2.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any attempt? Did you try the bootstrap official examples? Please research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the bootstrap example here http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

I think you want this? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/